# combine multiple columns into one

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

I came up with this query - how do I combine results from multiple columns into 1 ?

```
select 
    R2.start_time,
    TIME_FORMAT(time(R2.start_time - time(10000)),
            '%H:%i:%s') as '-60min',
    TIME_FORMAT(time(R2.start_time - time(3000)),
            '%H:%i:%s') as '-30min',
    TIME_FORMAT(time(R2.start_time + time(10000)) - time(3000),
            '%H:%i:%s') as 30min,
    TIME_FORMAT(time(R2.start_time + time(10000)),
            '%H:%i:%s') as 60min
from
    (select 
        rooms.id, rooms.number, rooms.building, rooms.capacity
    from
        rooms) R1,
    (select 
        exam_schedules.room_id,
            exam_schedules.day,
            exam_schedules.start_time,
            exam_schedules.end_time
    from
        exam_schedules) R2
where
    R2.room_id = R1.id and R2.day = 'tuesday' AND R1.number = 006
group by 1
```

this is my result:(1 row)

```
12:30:00    11:30:00    12:00:00    13:00:00    13:30:00
```

should be (5 rows):

```
12:30:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
13:00:00
13:30:00
```

Comment: you mean one column x one row OR one column x 5 rows

Comment: You are looking for `UNPIVOT`ing your results, there is no supporting function to do this in mysql, but the way I know to do this, and it is not elegant at all, is: `SELECT ccolumn1 from yourQuery UNION SELECT column2 from yourQuery ....`

Comment: Whats the point in the "group by 1" part?

Comment: too much for sql..it think.Try to do this in programming language part

Comment: @Peeyush, the question specifically asks how to achieve using SQL. You're assuming the query will be combiened with another programming lang. What if the asker wants to copy the results direct in to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from making use of a union statement here's an example of something you could do:

```
declare @dates table ( start_time datetime )

insert into @dates 
select GETDATE()

declare @offsets table ( offset int, seq int)

insert into @values
select 0, 1
union select -60, 2
union select -30, 3
union select 30, 4
union select 60, 5

select * from @dates

select 
    dateadd(minute, o.offset, r2.start_time) dt
from
    @dates r2, @offsets o
order by o.seq
```

Cant really test your query since I don't have your time functions, but you'd end up with something like this:

```
declare @offsets table ( offset int, seq int)

insert into @offsets
select 0, 1
union select -60, 2
union select -30, 3
union select 30, 4
union select 60, 5

select 
    dateadd(minute, o.offset, t.start_time) dt
from
(
select 
    R2.start_time as start_time
from
    (select 
        rooms.id, rooms.number, rooms.building, rooms.capacity
    from
        rooms) R1,
    (select 
        exam_schedules.room_id,
            exam_schedules.day,
            exam_schedules.start_time,
            exam_schedules.end_time
    from
        exam_schedules) R2
where
    R2.room_id = R1.id and R2.day = 'tuesday' AND R1.number = 006
group by 1
) t
, @offsets o
order by o.seq
```

Comment: Forgot to say that you can squeeze a bit more speed out of this by turning the offset table variable in to a proper table.

Answer (score 0):

If no of columns is fixed then you can try this one

```
SELECT col1 FROM yourtable UNION SELECT col2 FROM yourtable
```

I think it's not best way to do this but hope it can help you.